# Install Android to Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with GNU/Linux

Tags: installation, linux, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm looking forward to reinstall Android on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Are there compiled images for this device? 
Do I have to build it myself? If so, do I need propietary drivers from Samsung?

All the tutorials I found around require Windows (for Odin software) and installing mods and stuff like that, that sounds very hacky and dirty to me.

Comment: While dotVezz already placed a good answer (+1), some additional links for you to check: Our tag-wikis for [Heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) and [rom](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info) are good starters. Follow the links from there to more info, as well as questions using those tags.

Comment: See also [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a GNU/Linux-based OS, **you can use [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/), an open-source alternative to Odin** which is proported to match Odin feature-for-feature while also being more reliable. Otherwise, you can follow any of the many tutorials for installing a new Android ROM. I'll provide a bit more information to help you start your journey:

**If you want a custom ROM** like CyanogenMod or any of the dozens which are available in precompiled packages for specific devices, then you'll need to use Heimdall to flash a custom Recovery image ([TWRP](http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2/147) or [ClockWorkMod Recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager)). The zipped ROM images are flashable through these recovery modes.

**If you want stock, Samsung Android/Touchwiz** then you can use Heimdall to flash over the entire Android image from Samsung. (Google around to find the one for your model)

**If you want to compile Android yourself**, you'll likely want a custom Recovery image ([TWRP](http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2/147) or [ClockWorkMod Recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager)) and you can download the [Android source code](http://source.android.com/) or if you want to modify existing custom ROMs, you can download their respective source and compile it yourself. You'd need to hunt down some in-depth Android compiling tutorials in order to do this, as it's **not a simple process**.

*Note: Before flashing anything to your device, make sure that you match the model numbers!*